# RGeo::Geos.supported? shows as false even with -dev packages and symlink in place

Tags: rgeo

Trying to get the rgeo gem to recognise geos on an ubuntu 16.04 system.

I have the following packages installed:-

libgeos-dev, libgeos++-dev and libgeos-3.7.1

```
geos-config --version
3.7.1
```

I have a symlink in /usr/lib which points to the location of the version specific version in

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   42 Oct 21 18:05 libgeos.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos-3.7.1.so
```

Have run the following commands

```
gem uninstall rgeo
gem install rgeo -- --with-geos-dir=/usr/lib
```

However when I run the following it fails

```
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec irb
require 'rgeo'
RGeo::Geos.supported?
 => false
```

What am I doing wrong?  Have searched the various posts about this which has led me to install the -dev package and create the symlink, but still it doesnt work.

Have also added /usr/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and run ldconfig but without success.

Update

```
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec irb
2.5.0 :001 > require 'rgeo'
=> true
2.5.0 :002 > RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> true
2.5.0 :003 >
```

shows it working, but

```
Loading staging environment (Rails 5.2.0)
2.5.0 :001 > require 'rgeo'
=> false
2.5.0 :002 > RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> false
```

fails

and the app still shows

```
RGeo::Error::RGeoError (GEOS is not available, but is required for correct interpretation of polygons in shapefiles.)
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`spring stop` and restarting rails console fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that on CircleCi I needed to run these commands on ubuntu machine, then re-install rgeo gem

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgeos++-dev libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-dev libgeos-doc
gem unintsall rgeo
gem install rgeo
```

Comment: There is a typo in `unintsall`